# Como conectarme a PostgreSQL que se encuentra en un VPS

Tags: postgresql

Cordial saludo.

Actualmente estoy intentando conectarme a PostgreSQL ubicado en un VPS cuyo sistema es Linux, utilizando pgAdmin en mi pc.
Ya edite el archivo postgresql.conf en la parte de conexiones asi: `listen_addresses = '*'`

De igual forma, ya edite el archivo pg_hba.conf agregando la ip del VPS. Tambien modifique la contraseña de PostgresSQL y ya le aplique start a PostgreSQL para que tomara los cambios.

Luego, abro en mi pc pgAdmin para hacer la conexion a PostgreSQL. comienzo con el registro del servidor dandole un nombre, luego en la parte de connection le agrego la ip del VPS, dejo el puerto 5432 y pongo la contraseña de PostgreSQL. Cuando le doy guardar me aparece el siguiente error:

> "Unable to connect to server: connection to server at "IP VPS", port 5432 falled: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP publica de mi pc", user "postgres",database "postgres", SSL on connection to server at "IP VPS", port 5432 falled: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP publica de mi pc", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

Agradezco las indicaciones que me puedan brindar

Comment: Obviamente no existe ningún host cuya  ip sea `"IP que no conozco"`. Por favor, edita correctamente tu archivo de configuración.

Comment: Gracias por la observacion, ya cambie el comentario de "IP que no conozco" a "IP de mi pc"

Comment: Cuando dices "IP de mi pc" te refieres a un valor real ¿verdad? Estilo `172.17.0.1` o algún dominio donde está la base de datos, ten en cuenta que esa sección no es para "comentarios", es la sección que define el host al que te vas a conectar. Tu no pones "Ip del PC de google" para conectarte a google, tu pones "www.google.com".

Comment: Hola Jaime, me refiero a la IP publica de mi computador, del cual estoy tratando de conectar con el VPS. Normalmente en los videos que he visto, uno pone los datos del VPS (IP VPS) y la contraseña del postgreSQL del VPS y funciona, pero a mi me esta saliendo ese error

Comment: Ah, ok, tapaste tu ip para la pregunta. Disculpa la confusión. Es que acá diariamente se ven muchos errores de ese tipo y no sería extraño que alguien pusiera algo literal como "mi ip" en ese campo.

Comment: Utiliza DBeaver y realiza conexión SSH a tu server.

Comment: Hola fredyfx, agradezco tu osbervacion, pero mi deseo es trabajar con pgadmin

Comment: Acabo de validar que el servidor VPS tiene el puerto 5432 LISTEN, ya que  pensé que esa era el problema ya que el puerto en el programa de PostgreSQL también lo tiene abierto. Continuo buscando una solución y atento a sus respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo.
Para poder lograr la conexión remota a PostgeSQL, se debe editar dos archivos.
El primero esta ubicado en:

```
/etc/postgresql/10/main
```

el archivo se llama postgresql.conf, se debe abrir y encontrar la linea:

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

y cambiarla por:

```
listen_addresses = '*' (como puedes notar quiete el signo numeral o almohadilla para que no sea un comentario).
```

El segundo paso, es en la ubicacion:

```
/etc/postgresql/10/main
```

abrir el archivo pg_hba.conf y en la sección donde encontraras esta líneas:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

proceder a agregar estas otras dos:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

luego guarda el archivo y procede desde consola a reiniciar el servicio de postgresql en el servidor remoto utilizando el comando:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service.
```

Al hacer esto, abrí en mi pc el programa pgadmin, configure la conexión y listo, ya tengo acceso.

Comment: Nota al pie: 0.0.0.0/0 abre la conexión a TODAS las IP. Eso sirve si tu IP es dinámica. Eso pudo ser parte del problema